# File not found in airflow

Tags: python, azure, airflow, azure-pipelines-yaml, astronomer

I'm using astro-cli for running airflow
I have folder structure as follows:
astro-cli:

```
dags(dir)
include(dir)
test.yaml
airflow_settings.yaml
Dockerfile
```

when I fire this command in my airflow dag

```
cmd_dataprep = az ml job create -f test.yaml --resource-group DefaultResourceGroup-EUS2 --workspace-name test-airflow
```

I'm getting error

```
[2023-01-15, 14:29:57 UTC] {subprocess.py:75} INFO - Running command: ['/bin/bash', '-c', 'az ml job create -f test.yaml --resource-group DefaultResourceGroup-EUS2 --workspace-name test-airflow']
[2023-01-15, 14:29:57 UTC] {subprocess.py:86} INFO - Output:
[2023-01-15, 14:29:59 UTC] {subprocess.py:93} INFO - ERROR: [31m
[2023-01-15, 14:29:59 UTC] {subprocess.py:93} INFO - 
[2023-01-15, 14:29:59 UTC] {subprocess.py:93} INFO - Error: The yaml file you provided does not match the prescribed schema for General yaml files and/or has the following issues:
[2023-01-15, 14:29:59 UTC] {subprocess.py:93} INFO - 
[2023-01-15, 14:29:59 UTC] {subprocess.py:93} INFO - 1) One or more files or folders do not exist.

[2023-01-15, 14:29:59 UTC] {subprocess.py:93} INFO - No such file or directory: test.yaml
```

What am I missing?

Edit: dag

```
task_dataprep = BashOperator(
task_id='run_dataprep',
bash_command=cmd_dataprep,
dag=dag)
```

Comment: Can you post the DAG task and maybe the DAG ?

Comment: @enslaved_programmer added dag

Comment: That was the task, but please add the method cmd_dataprep.

Comment: Sorry, i forget to mention it, added it now

Comment: You most likely need to put it in your dags folder and then change path to `../test.yaml`

Comment: i have tried it too, still the error continues

Answer (score 1):

It's recommended to provide the absolute path of your files

```bash
cmd_dataprep = az ml job create -f /path/to/test.yaml --resource-group DefaultResourceGroup-EUS2 --workspace-name test-airflow
```

And you need to ensure that your file is accessible from all Airflow workers if you are using Celery or Kubernetes executors.

Comment: Adding to that: by default the BashOperator will execute its commands in a temporary directory (something like `/tmp/airflowtmp51vqpgmm`). So you might also need to set the `cwd` parameter of the BashOperator to your root directory.